# I am submitting a form using php & jquery ajax using formdata but the url part seems to be not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, form-data

I am just trying to submit a form using jquery ajax and for that i m using the FormData but whenever i click on the submit button the page reloads without showing any kind of error or any kind of result.

This is the Form Part name is regpage.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>reg form</title>

<script
              src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

              <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3-jquery.min.js"></script>

                <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #d1
        {
            width: 400px;
            height: auto;
            border: 1px solid;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    </style>
    </head>





</head>
<body>
<form id="form"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div id="d1">

<h1>Regestration form</h1>
username:<input type="text" name="uname" id="username" placeholder="username"><br>
password:<input type="password" name="pass" id="password" placeholder="password"><br>
email:<input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email"><br>
<span>Hobby</span>
<input type="checkbox" name="cric[]"  value="cricket">Cricket
<input type="checkbox" name="cric[]"  value="kite">Kite
<input type="checkbox" name="cric[]"  value="zym">ZYM<br>

<h2>Gender</h2>
<input type="radio" name="chack" id="d3" value="male">male
<input type="radio" name="chack" id="d3" value="female">female<br>
<input type="file" name="image" action="image/*" ><br>
<input type="submit" name="sub" value="sign up"   ><br>

</div>
</form>
<div id="output" ></div>
<script >
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $("#form").on('submit',(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({

            url: "aform.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:  new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            beforeSend : function()
            {
                //$("#preview").fadeOut();
                $("#output").fadeOut();
            },
            success: function(data)
            {
                if(data=='invalid')
                {
                    // invalid file format.
                    $("#output").html("Invalid File !").fadeIn();
                }
                else
                {
                    // view uploaded file.
                    $("#preview").html(data).fadeIn();
                    $("#form")[0].reset();  
                }
            },
            error: function(e) 
            {
                $("#output").html(e).fadeIn();
            }           
       });
    }));
});

</script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Now here is the page where i am trying to send the form

```
    <?php


print_r($_POST);

$valid_extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'bmp'); // valid extensions
$path = 'uploads/'; // upload directory


if(isset($_FILES['image']))
{
extract($_POST);

  $hobby=implode(',','cric');

  $img = $_FILES['iname']['name'];
  $tmp = $_FILES['iname']['tmp_name'];

  // get uploaded file's extension
  $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($img, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

  // can upload same image using rand function
  $final_image = rand(1000,1000000).$img;



  // check's valid format
  if(in_array($ext, $valid_extensions)) 
  {         
    $path = $path.strtolower($final_image); 

    if(move_uploaded_file($tmp,$path)) 
    {
      $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","users");

      $qry="insert into abcd(username,password,email,hobby,gender,image)values('$uname','$pass','$email','$hobby','$chack','$image') ";

      mysqli_query($con,$qry);

      //print_r($run);
      echo "<img src='$path' />";
    }
  } 
  else 
  {
    echo 'invalid';
  }
}


?>
```

What I am Doing Wrong can anyone Tell me about it?

Comment: is there any error in console?

Comment: For one, you'er vulnerble to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). For seconds, you have essentially NO error handling, and are simply ASSUMING that nothing could ever possibly go wrong. For thirds, the path you're (trying to?) save the image into will **NOT** work as a `src` for web usage.

Comment: so i should add error handling and remove the image upload from it @Marc B ?

Comment: if you need the image, then what'd be the point of removing it? But start checking for failure. Because you're ASSUMING everything is perfect, you have no idea if something DID actually go wrong. Never **EVER** assume success when dealing with external resources. Always assume failure, check for failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise.

Comment: ok let me try by adding error handling in my code thanks for the reply @Marc B

Comment: but can you check if i have done any major syntax  error in my code @Marc B